# Consulta Firebase. Android

Tags: android, firebase

Tengo una duda respecto a Firebase con Android
Realizo la consulta obteniendo un string con el siguiente resultado:

```
String S= "{Centro 1={Wifi=458pohh875, Freedns=centrouno.mooo.com, Webkey=h64792390hyd}, Centro 2={Wifi=2910393, Freedns=centrodos.mooo.com, Webkey=jugi8jk9jk}}"
```

Cual seria la manera mas sencilla de pasar esos datos a una `listview` con un adaptador personalizado? he visto varias pero se me hacen un poco complicadas de aplicar ya que apenas empiezo con la programación..

como podría convertir esos datos a formato `JSON`?

Comment: Según recuerdo Firebase ya te regresa los datos en formato Json listos para serializarlos en un objeto y usarlos en un adapter para mostrarlos en un recyclerview https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/retrieving-data.html

Comment: La manera más simple de serializar el Json seria usando [JsonObject](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html). Ahora si estas usando Firebase eso ya esta resuelto, Seguramente tenes un "Snapshoot" que representa al objeto serializado. [Docs oficiales](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/retrieve-data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo recomendaría el uso de algún ORM, para evitar tener que deserializar, y así tendrías todo en objetos Java, te recomiendo sugar ORM, es fácil entenderlo e implementarlo, y tu codigo estará mucho mejor organizado.

http://satyan.github.io/sugar/

Una vez teniendo la información de las tablas en Objetos Java, ya solo los utilizas en el componente android de tu agrado.

Saludos

Answer (score 1):

La manera mas sencilla de usar firebase con un ListView es usando una libreria que se llama [FirebaseUI](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/README.md)

Te dejo un breve ejemplo extraido del sitio de la libreria.

```
ListView messagesView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.messages_list);
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
mAdapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<Chat>(this, Chat.class, android.R.layout.two_line_list_item, ref) {
    @Override
    protected void populateView(View view, Chat chatMessage, int position) {
        ((TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setText(chatMessage.getName());
        ((TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text2)).setText(chatMessage.getText());

    }
};
messagesView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Esa librería la mantiene la misma gente de Firebase y la podes usar tanto para ListView como para RecycleView.